# Why can't PHP see the text file I want to fopen() in the same directory?

Tags: php

All I want to do is `fopen()` a text file in my PHP script. It's the most important part of the module that I'm building. Unfortunately, while testing the script, I found that the script cannot see the text file that I'd like to open. I have the script in the same directory as the text file, but I keep getting met with the same error. I'm posting the script code snippet and the command line prompt/response below.

**Code**

```
$membersfile = fopen('./members.txt', 'r');
print_r($membersfile);
fclose($membersfile);
```

**Command Line**

> 507 elersong:~$ php /Users/elersong/Desktop/SS2014/register_member.php
>
> Warning: fopen(./members.txt): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in
>   /Users/elersong/Desktop/SS2014/register_member.php on line 11
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /Users/elersong/Desktop/SS2014/register_member.php on line 13

I have no clue why PHP can't see the file since it most certainly exists, and it's in the same directory as the script. Please help me make sense of this.

Comment: Are you really sure there is a file `members.txt`
 in the folder `/Users/elersong/Desktop/SS2014/`?

Comment: Use  fopen('members.txt', 'r');

Comment: File owner/permissions?

Comment: @wumm, I'd stake my life on it.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, that doesn't work either. It boggles me.

Comment: @MarkBaker, even when I try it using `sudo` I get the same error.

Comment: try `echo '<pre>';var_dump(glob('*'));` should show files in current dir

Comment: How are you trying `sudo` from within PHP? Is this running as a web script or CLI?

Comment: @MarkBaker, I'm making a bash call to php and running the script on the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Some PHP setups have problems with relative parts, so try this instead:

```
fopen(__DIR__ . '/members.txt', 'r');
```

`__DIR__` contains the path to the folder where the currently executing PHP file is.

Your are currently doing:

```
$membersfile = fopen(__DIR__ .'/members.txt', 'r');
print_r($membersfile); 
fclose($membersfile);
```

But `$membersfile` contains just the handle, a number so that PHP nows which opened file you are meaning. If you print that you will just see the handle number. You need to tell pHP to read the file using:

```
$file = __DIR__ .'/members.txt';
$membersfile = fopen($file, 'r');
echo fread($membersfile, filesize($file))
fclose($membersfile);
```

or use the php shorthand function:

```
echo file_get_contents( __DIR__ .'/members.txt');
```

Comment: I get the following result at the command line, but I don't understand it. Please advise.
`Resource id #5512 elersong:~$`

Comment: @elersong That's is because your are doing `print_r($membersfile);`, which prints the handle.

Comment: @elersong What you want is most likely `echo fread($membersfile, filesize($filename))` instead of `print_r($membersfile);`

Comment: @elersong yeah what wumm said or use `file_get_contents` instead of `fopen`

Answer (score -1):

After trying a number of the suggestions posted here, I was finally able to figure out that the PHP script isn't using a relative path to the text file based on the directory that holds the PHP script.

User @andrew suggested that I add the following line to my script in order to learn which directory the script uses as its starting point.

`echo '<pre>';var_dump(glob('*'));`

From the output of this line, I was able to see that the script uses the user's root folder as the starting point in `fopen()` on my OSX machine. I simply needed to preface the filename with the remainder of the file path, and PHP could read it. The amended script is as follows:

`$membersfile = fopen('Desktop/SS2014/members.txt', 'r');`

Thanks so much, @andrew and everyone else who submitted suggestions!